# How to fetch & display associated (referenced collection) data in EJS template?

Tags: express, ejs

I have associated collections as you can see below. Within an EJS template where I am displaying blogs, I would like to display related comments for each blog as well.

```
Model Structure:
Blog
..title (string)
..blog (string)
..comments (Referenced Comment Model) 
....comment (string)

Comment
..comment(string)
```

I have the following code to query for data and pass it to EJS template:

```
app.get('/blog',function(req,res){
  Blog.find({},function(err,blogs){
    if(err){
      console.log('can not get blogs from db!!');
    } else {
      res.render('pages/blogs', {blogs: blogs});
    }
  });
});
```

Although data received by EJS includes comments data, I can not display comments with my following EJS code:

```
  <h2>Blog Posts</h2>
  <% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
    <div>
      <h3>Title: <%= blog.title %></h3>
      <p>Blog Post: <%= blog.blog %></p>
      <p>Comments </p>
        <% blog.comments.forEach(function(blogComment){ %>
            <span><%= blogComment.comment %></span>
        <%}) %>
    </div>
  <% }) %>
```

When I put following code on the EJS, I can see the id's of the related comments:

```
<span>Comments: <%= blog.comments %> </span>
```

**Comments: 5a9d070609a0f31f33b99de8,5a9d0728083d5d1f672956cb**

Would you please explain how I can display comments (referenced data) on EJS template?

Answer (score 0):

After reading thoroughly, I found that associated data needs to be populated before feeding into EJS template. So correct DB query is as follows. Please note the`).populate("comments").exec(` insertion:

```
app.get('/blog',function(req,res){
  Blog.find({}).populate("comments").exec(function(err,blogs){
    if(err){
      console.log('can not get blogs from db!!');
    } else {
      res.render('pages/blogs', {title: "All Blog Posts", blogs: blogs});
    }
  });
});
```